# How do I use asp:hyperlink with databinding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, hyperlink

I thought I had this one pretty good, but I just keep running into an error

Am I doing anything wrong in the code that you can see?

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format(~/storefront.aspx?CatalogID={0}&ProductID={1}",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CatalogID"),DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CustItem")) %>' >
```

Is there another method I could use any help on the matter is appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: You have an orphaned double quote at the end of ProductID, I'm not sure its needed => &ProductID={1}"

Comment: Thanks for catching that, however, it did not solve the problem, I do not know the exact error, the way this site is set up, if there is an error it takes you to an error page that has been made.. but I do know that if I take out the # at the beginning I get an HTTP 400 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an open quote in the String.Format function. Try this instead:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("~/storefront.aspx?CatalogID={0}&ProductID={1}", Eval("CatalogID"), Eval("CustItem"))%>'></asp:HyperLink>
```